# How to seal the lock with cryptography

Tags: encryption, man-in-the-middle, decryption

I am new in the world of cryptography. I'm working with an IoT project. My job is to protect the entire data. So, I need some cryptographic security.

I want that data should be encrypted before transmitting to the internet.

So, if the encrypted data (with digital signature) is transmitted through HTTPS protocol, then it should be secure. If my data is changed somehow when transmitting (middle-man-attack), then at the time of verifying it wouldn't qualify.

But, here is a problem: if somehow the encrypted data is changed with another encrypted data which are successfully qualified when I decrypt it, then what happens?

So, I want something like...

1. Generate data
2. Put this data in a box
3. Lock this box
4. Seal the lock

And I want that at the time of receiving I first check the seal is broken or not, if not then verify the signed data.

How to implement this system? Is it a good idea or not?

Comment: " if somehow the encrypted data is changed with another encrypted data which are successfully qualified when I decrypt it" -- can you rephrase that? It is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I mean digital signature (public key encryption)

Comment: Your pictures do not help your explanation, so I have removed them. It appears that you are trying to use an analogy, but you have not explained your analogy. What is a "box"?

Comment: I think that you are confusing public key encryption with digital signatures. Those are different concepts. And I think that encrypting ***and*** signing is what you want to do since that meets your requirements. I'm not sure how a man-in-the-middle can replace the data, as you describe. And I think you need to look up "authentication" as a function of encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, if encrypted (with digital signature) data is transmit through HTTPS protocol then it should be secure. So, if my data is changed somehow in the time of transmitting (middle-man-attack) then at the time of verify it would't qualify.

First of all, encryption provides secrecy. No-one can read what you're sending. It does not provide integrity or authentication.

However, https provides both. It encrypts data, and it authenticates the parties. Normally, only the server is authenticated, but client side certificates, or additional authentication (e.g. client identifier of some sort) may be transmitted to authenticate the client.

You probably do not need any additional encryption; TLS (https) should be enough. If you need to ensure integrity of the data, you may want to look into [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), which lets you sign the individual messages.